# Visualize frames + debug text in DrakeVisualizer

Tags: drake

Can we:

1. Draw the body frames for each object in Drake Visualizer?

and

2. Append a small debug text? Similar to how in pyBullet. You provide a world position and string, and it displays in the visualizer.

In absence of 2, is there a way to visualize the quantitative frame values in DrakeVisualizer associated with each body?